# bash script move file to folders based in name

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I hope you can help me...

I made a perl and bash script to make a backup of my firewalls and tranfers via tftp

```
#!/bin/sh 

 perl /deploy/scripts/backups/10.160.23.1.pl > /dev/null 2>&1
 perl /deploy/scripts/backups/10.160.23.2.pl > /dev/null 2>&1
```

so this tranfers the file to my tftp directory /tftpboot/

```
ls -l /tftpboot/
total 532
-rw-rw-rw- 1 tftp tftp 209977 jun  6 14:01 10.160.23.1_20140606.cfg
-rw-rw-rw- 1 tftp tftp 329548 jun  6 14:02 10.160.23.2_20140606.cfg
```

my questions is how to improve my script to moving this files dynamically to another folder based on the name (in this case on the ip address)

**for example:**
10.160.23.1_20140606.cfg move to /deploy/backups/10.160.23.1/

is that the answer to this surely was on Google, but wanted to know if there was a particular solution to this request and also learn how to do :)

Thanks!

Comment: is this intra network?  Or is this ftp server far away from you?

Answer (score 1):

Simply transform the filename into data space, then manipulate it to extract the information you want, then use the information. **NOTE:** For production, use a more constrained file match than `/tftpboot/*.cfg`

```
#!/bin/bash  
for file in /tftpboot/*.cfg ; do
    ipaddr=$( echo "$file" | cut -d/ -f3 | cut -d_ -f1 )  
    [ -d /deploy/backups/${ipaddr} || mkdir -p /deploy/backups/${ipaddr}  
    mv --verbose "$file" /deploy/backups/${ipaddr}/
done
```